# IndentationError: unexpected indent, thrown by Python 3. Code used in Kubernetes args entry in Pod deployment YAML

Tags: python, kubernetes, yaml, containers, google-kubernetes-engine

*goal and the issue*

To have a container/Pod deployment that can be continously running. The command the container should execute is: `/usr/local/bin/python3` and the args to the command are: `"-c $'import time\\nwhile (True):\\n print(\".\");time.sleep(5);'"`. However, when I execute `kubectl apply -f "PATH_TO_THE_KUBERNETES_YAML_FILE"` the deployment errs with this Python exception: `IndentationError: unexpected indent`.

A screenshot of the error: [image]

The Pod deployment is used as the medium for calling Python code that interacts with the **Certbot** client as part of tasks when using LetsEncrypt certificates.

See the project [here](https://github.com/larssb/LetsEncryptIT)

So it should be possible to deploy the Pod >> do a `kubectl exec ...` into the container running as part of the Kubernetes deployment.

*tried:*

Various ways of defining the Kubernetes command args line.

1. Via the **exec** Python option. E.g.: `python3 -c exec(\"import time\nwhile True: print(\".\");time.sleep(5);\")`
2. Enclosing the code to execute with different combinations of **`** and **"**.
3. `$'textwrap.dedent("""import time while True: print(".") time.sleep(5)""")'`...
4. tried using:

   ```
   args:
    - "-c $'import time\\nwhile (True):\\n print(\".\");time.sleep(5);'"
   ```

   as an alternative to `args: ["-c $'import time\\nwhile (True):\\n print(\".\");time.sleep(5);'"]`
5. confirmed that the Python code itself works.
6. both by using `Python3 -c "..."` directly and by calling it via a `docker run` command [to a container from this Dockerfile](https://github.com/larssb/LetsEncryptIT/blob/develop/docker/LetsencryptIT/dockerfile)
7. I have done the usual Googling, Stack* search and so forth. I've also been on the official Kubernetes GitHub repo page and search through the issues there. Closed as well as open. And I have not seen any issue matching this one.
8. **Kubectl** does not complain when doing `...apply -f YAML_FILE`, in regards to the format of the YAML file and to the adherence of the Pod deployment specification.
9. Tried with some bash code instead: `["/bin/bash", "-ecx", "while :; do printf '.'; sleep 5 ; done"]`<-- that works.

*further info*

- Python is v3.7.2
- Kubernetes is v1.12.5-gke.10

---

It seems to be the combination of specifying the Python code in a Kubernetes Pod deployment YAML file ... that doesn't go well with Pythons requirement of significant whitespace and indentation. As you can read in the #tried section, it works when calling Python directly or via a Docker run/exec command.

How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Where does it say the unexpected indent come from?

Comment: Why do you want to provide the complete code via `-c`? Why not just write it to a file and run the file? If you really want to run that code you can use `python -c $'import time\nwhile True: print("."); time.sleep(5);'`. No need to use new lines for the while suite since you can join simple statements by semicolons as described [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html).

Comment: @a_guest thank you for the suggestion. I've actually tried that. See bullet point 1 in my question.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 - I added a screenshot of the error. It points to the start of the line. Which is not that helpful.

Comment: @LarsBingchong Bullet point 1 reads `python3 -c exec(\"import time\nwhile True: print(\".\");time.sleep(5);\")` which is substantially different from what I suggested `python -c $'import time\nwhile True: print("."); time.sleep(5);'` as it contains an additional call to `exec` (why? did you check `man exec` to confirm it's doing what you want?) and some additional backslashes which I can't make sense of. You might also want to read `man python` and scroll down to section "Interpreter Interface"; an excerpt: *"when called with -c command, it executes the Python statement(s) given as command."*.

Comment: @a_guest I tried the `exec` option as the other tries I have been through did not work. Again I think this is likely the combination of Kubernetes YAML for a POD deployment and Python. As it works when called directly on the cmdline or via a "regular" Docker container. To me that the statement is executed as a `command` is quite alright. Is there something in particular I should be observant on?

Comment: @LarsBingchong To work around the issue (instead of solve it), have you tried removing the newline-space after the colon after the `while`?

Comment: Hi @wizzwizz4 - I did `$'import time\nwhile True:print('.'); time.sleep(5);` and the same issue remains. Unfortunately :-). I just added a couple of extra tags to this question. So that people looking for Kubernetes issues/questions hopefully will also find it.

Answer (score 1):

So I was able to get help on this on the Kubernetes Slack channel. It was a YAML syntax issue.

### The following in the Pod deployment YAML file solved it

```
  args:
    - |-
      -c
      import time
      while True:
          print('.')
          time.sleep(5)
```

this works in combination with the Dockerfile's....

```
FROM larssb/certbot-dns-cloudflare-python3
LABEL author="https://github.com/larssb"

#
# Container config
#
WORKDIR /letsencryptit

#
# COPY IN DATA
#
COPY ./scripts /scripts/
COPY ./letsencryptit /letsencryptit/

#
# INSTALL
#
RUN pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client --disable-pip-version-check --no-cache-dir \
    && pip install --upgrade oauth2client --disable-pip-version-check --no-cache-dir \
    && pip install --upgrade sty --disable-pip-version-check --no-cache-dir \
    && chmod +x /scripts/deploy-hook-runner.sh

# Set an ENTRYPOINT to override the entrypoint specified in certbot/certbot
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/python3"]
CMD ["-c"]
```

`ENTRYPOINT`, as this is re-used by the Pod deployment. However, the Dockerfile's `CMD` is overwritten by the `args` property in the Pod deployment YAML file.

### The args property explained in detail

- The `-c` is a parameter to the Python binary
- The rest is std. Python code, to have the container, deployed via the Pod deployment, continuously run so that it can be on standby for command calls to it via `kubectl exec`

### The key

This part of the `args` property > `- |-`. It strips the line feed and any trailing blank lines. Making it possible to state a multi-line Python block of code

### Documentation

- A gist with example code on the required syntax in the `args` property. Find it [here](https://gist.github.com/grampelberg/f4d2b2f17e037d303c07ac585dd52781).
- The [Dockerfile](https://github.com/larssb/LetsEncryptIT/blob/develop/docker/LetsencryptIT/dockerfile) used
- The Kubernetes Pod deployment YAML file. Check it out [here](https://github.com/larssb/LetsEncryptIT/blob/develop/kubernetes/deploys/letsencryptit-pod.yml)
- [On the YAML "strip" syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21699210/2191231)

---

Kudos to @wizzwizz4, @a_guest for your comments and suggestions. They helped me troubleshoot this, narrow in on a solution.
Also a big thank you to Mr. @grampelberg on the Kubernetes Slack channel for assisting me and providing the solution.